# What determines 'A' type in foldLeft?

Tags: scala

In this definition of foldLeft where List of Ints are reversed :

```
  val l = List(1, 2)                              //> l  : List[Int] = List(1, 2)
  l.foldLeft(List[Int]())((b, a) => a :: b)       //> res2: List[Int] = List(2, 1)
```

How is `A` typed to an Int in foldLeft function ?

Source for foldLeft is :

```
  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    var acc = z
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      acc = f(acc, these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
    acc
  }
```

What determines the `A` type ? Is there some Scala implicit logic occurring that determines `Int` type from type parameter `List[Int]` ?

Update :

foldLeft is defined in LinearSeqOptimized.

When list is created using `val l = List(1,2)` this also types the `A` parameter to `LinearSeqOptimized` as it is part of its object hierarchy :

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A]
                                  with LinearSeq[A]
                                  with Product
                                  with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List]
                                  with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]]
                                  with Serializable {
```

This is why type `A` is typed to Int in `foldLeft` ?

Comment: `A` is the list element type.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if we practiced the same sort of care in naming at the type level as at the value level?

Comment: @acjay agree, but single char variable names for types makes extracting meaning from these names more difficult which I think can lead to mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foldLeft[B]` is a member of `List[A]` (and many different collection types). So the `A` is just the type parameter of the collection you are folding.

`List(1, 2)` is a `List[Int]`, so `A = Int`.

`B` is then the type you are folding into (the return type of `fold`). It might be the same as `A`, but it might not. In your example, you are folding into a `List[Int]`, so `B = List[Int]` (not `Int`).

Comment: thanks, please see update. Am I understanding this correctly ?

Comment: @blue-sky I'm not sure I understand your follow up question. Your edit doesn't really say anything about `B`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: apologies, I have updated question to read "This is why type A is typed to Int in foldLeft" instead of "This is why type B is typed to Int in foldLeft".

Comment: @blue-sky Yes, `A` is inferred to be `Int` when you create `List(1, 2)`, which must also be the same for all of the traits `List` mixes in.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell

```
List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(List[Int]())((b, a) => a :: b)
     ^                 ^
     A                 B
```